# S3 Generic for a List of Tibbles, Data.Frames, Matrices, Ect

Tags: r

I'm kind of puzzled like this. Obviously, if I create a function with generic methods for tibbles, data.frames, and matrices, as such:

```
dummy_func <- function(data) { 
    UseMethod("dummy_func") 
} 

dummy_func.tbl_df <- function(data) { 
data <- tibble_data
#do something down-stream
} 

dummy_func.data.frame <- function(data) { 
data <- data_frame_one
#do something down-stream
}
```

R will know which one to use since the variable `data` will be associated with that type. However, what happens if I have a list of a specific object:

```
 dummy_func.tbl_df <- function(data_list) { 
    data_list <- list_of_tibble_data
    #do something down-stream
    }
```

Can R recognize that the data_list in this generic method is associated with a list of tibbles?  And same with a list of data.frames, etc?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The short answer is "no", but it's easy to achieve the desired action by using an S3 `dummy_func.list` method that checks the contents of any list passed. For simplicity we will get it to just report the type of the contents of the list passed to it, but obviously you might want the conditional branches to have specific actions for different types.

```r
dummy_func <- function(data) { 
    UseMethod("dummy_func") 
} 

dummy_func.list <- function(data) { 
  types <- sapply(data, function(x) class(x)[1])
  if(all(types == "data.frame")) return("A list of data frames was passed")
  if(all(types == "tbl_df")) return("A list of tibbles was passed")
  stop("Need a list of all data frames or all tibbles")
}
```

So we can test it like this:

```r
# Dummy tibble and dummy dataframe
my_tibble     <- dplyr::tibble(a = 1:3)
my_df         <- data.frame(a = 1:3)

# Dummy lists
my_tbl_list   <- list(my_tibble, my_tibble)
my_df_list    <- list(my_df, my_df)
my_mixed_list <- list(my_tibble, my_df)

# Test dispatch:
dummy_func(my_tbl_list)
#> [1] "A list of tibbles was passed"

dummy_func(my_df_list)
#> [1] "A list of data frames was passed"

dummy_func(my_mixed_list)
#> Error in dummy_func.list(my_mixed_list): Need a list of all data frames or all tibbles
```